# How do I look at what landing page is bringing me sales on ecommerce?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, shopify

I'm using shopify so the ecommerce tracking is already set up and working well.

Now what I what to know is which landing pages are making how much money and % of people adding to cart.

Once I have that if I could split it by OS and age that would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

This is already a pre-defined report from Google, if you have ecommerce tracking enabled.  Go to Behavior > Site Content > Landing Pages where you'll get the landing page report.  Make sure the "Conversions" tab shows eCommerce.

Like this screen shot:

https://snag.gy/IpXsAt.jpg

As far as the add to cart, you'll have to create goals and funnels for arrival at the checkout.  This article on shopify should help, it's step by step for creating the funnels.  https://help.shopify.com/manual/reports-and-analytics/google-analytics/google-analytics-goals-and-funnels

Additionally if you add the "Add to Cart" as an event, you can add that event as the secondary dimension on the landing page report to figure out how many add to cart, but don't convert.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer, it seems to be bugging out cause all my sales should be coming from the landing page with very high views, but some of them are coming from /shipping or stuff like that. Which doesn't really make sense, or does it? 

You can see what it looks like here http://imgur.com/kzBtoD4 (I blanked out after the /products/ but the rest is the same)

Comment: It could be people coming back to complete transaction after an interruption.  This is why capturing the funnel will help you out.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, I was able to create a funnel and see my amount of thank you page visits and everything. one thing I wasn't able to do though is know the amount of sales in $ that a landing page is bring me. Is that possible? Also is it possible to share the stats of only one landing page with someone without having them be able to see how all my other landing pages are doing?

Comment: Are you not seeing that now? Maybe post a screen shot?   For client reporting, I usually export to excel and show what they need to see.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. here's a screen shot of the behaviors -> landing pages http://imgur.com/a/LghBx . And here's a screenshot of the goal pages http://imgur.com/a/RzKNs . Maybe I'm not looking at the right place?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem?  Do you have multiple landing pages, or the one /products/ landing page?  Do all of your pages have the GA tracking code enabled?